# Does a circuit going into an Arduino pin/GND need a resistor?

Tags: arduino, resistors, ground, pins

If a circuit goes into an Arduino pin, even the GND pin, but does not use something a component that needs a resistor such as an LED, does it still need a resistor for the Arduino *pin*?

**Edit:** To clear this question up, here's an example of what I mean.

Imagine a circuit with *no components*. It's pointless, but it's just for demonstation. Say that the circuit comes out from the 5V pin on the Arduino and goes into the GND pin again immediately; that's all it does. Because the circuit has current going in to the GND pin, does it need a resistor?

**Edit again:** Here's a picture of what I mean. Would this need a resistor?
[image]

Comment: Is this something being driven by the Arduino pin as a digital out? Would you please give a concrete example of "a component that [does not] need a resistor"? Otherwise this question seems too vague.

Comment: What do you mean by "circuit goes into an Arduino pin?" Do you mean a *connection* to a component?

Comment: I've edited my question to clear things up a bit!

Comment: Yes, that circuit needs a resistor, but for the simple reason that otherwise you're shorting the power supply. Anyway, thank you for the edit, I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: You almost need to give us a specific case. In your simple example, you must, but only because you're directly shorting your 5V to ground, so the resistor would act as the load and current limiter. In other cases, a resistor may not be needed if the circuit being connected to the 5V pin regulates it's own power.

Comment: Your edit shows shorting out the power supply. That is a no no. Overall, this still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Arduino's GND, 5V and 3.3V pins, have *very different* behaviour from an Arduino pin being used as a digital Output.

The GND and 5V pins is connected directly to the power supply. They are not connected to the ATmega microcontroller.

When the Arduino is being powered by USB, the 5V pin can supply (source) up to 500mA. The GND pin and can 'absorb' (sink) up to 500mA. This is much more than all of the Arduino's digital out pins combined can handle (source or sink).

The Arduino's ATmega is also using some of that 500mA. The ATmega's maximum current use is approximately 200mA, though it is typically much less.

The 3.3V pin is supplied by a smaller voltage regulator . The [Arduino UNO specification](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) syas the 3.3V pin can supply (source) 50mA.

The 5V and 3.3V pins must *never* be connected directly to any GND pin. There must *always* be enough resistance to limit the current flowing from 5V to (500mA - ATmega) or less. The ATmega does not use the 3.3V supply, so the resistance limiting the current flowing from 3.3V must limit current to 50mA or less.

An Arduino pin, when set to digital output, can handle (source or sink) a *maximum* of 40mA. (While remaining within the ATmega's specification)

Pins on an ATmega are grouped into 8-pin 'ports'. When several pins on the same port are being used, then the maximum current from all the pins on the port is 100mA. I generally use  12mA as a maximum current, while I am experimenting. I usually enforce that limit using a resistor.

When an Arduino pin is used as a digital input, for a voltage within its safe operating range, it doesn't matter about limiting current with a resistor because an input pin already has a very high impedance (resistance).

When an input voltage might be outside the safe operating range for an input pin, then there are many choices.

Each Arduino pin has small diodes connecting it to Vcc (e.g. 5V) and ground, arranged so that a voltage below ground or above Vcc applied to the pin will be conducted to one of those rails. These diodes only handle small currents. So the pin can be protected from moderate voltage shorts (say under 12V) by putting a resistor on the input pin.

(I have scoured the ATmega328 data sheet but can't find a spec for these protection diodes, I believe they are rated well under 1mA)

A more predictable solution is to explicitly protect the input pins using a resistor to limit current, and diodes to the Vcc and ground rail.

(More robust and complex solutions to protect a pin exist, but these cover the simple case.)

Comment: Sometimes you use a resistor on an input pin if there's any chance it will be driven beyond the supply rails, in order to limit the current through the protection diodes.

Comment: Good point. I will add that as a separate case, and clarify the 'default'. In situations where I expect that, I would use an active device (e.g. zenner) to hold the voltage within safe limits.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect an LED to an Arduino pin, you absolutely need to include a series resistor. The reason for this is, without it the current will not be limited (except by physics of course). Since the ATmega328P can source up to 40mA you'll either burn up your LED or blow your output driver, whichever happens first.

Edit: In response to your updated question. DON'T DO THAT! You're computer will shut down the USB port if it's smart, and if it's not smart it will almost certainly damage it. Bad things happen when you connect a power source to GND with low resistance. OHMS LAW: current = change in voltage / resistance. If you connect 5V to GND you will have a change in resistance of 5V, and if you connect it with lets say a wire resistance of 0.1 ohms, you will conduct a current of 5/0.1 = 50A. You will never get there though because something will shut-down / burn up / break first.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the the question. The OP seems to understand that an LED needs a resistor; he's asking about other situations.

Comment: @DaveTweed it was difficult to parse... :)